# Should I be using whitespaces when using inline style syntaxes?

Tags: html, css

Is it more practical to not use whitespaces in this scenario?

```
style="color:white;font-size:24px"
```

or

```
style="color: white; font-size: 24px"
```

Comment: it doesn't matter

Comment: It depends on the project, for me that' part of formatting and in each project you can have different rules of formatting, you should be coherent and do It in the same way in the project, is like having } having a space at the end or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not actually matter. 
The second approach would be better aesthetically but it hardly matters in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This for me is part of Code Style, the Code Style does not change the behavior so It really does not matter for the final user but It is important to state some rules (you could create a Scheme of rules for your IDE) so that everyone in your project uses the same. The most important thing is to be COHERENT and do It in the same way in the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter at all. You can use `whitespaces`. Imagine you have below style added.

```
style="color:white;font-size:24px;width:200px"
```

Also you can do it as:

```
style="color:white; font-size:24px; width:200px"
```

This one is good for understanding purpose. you can use `whitespaces`. It's better because when using `whitespaces` it is very clear and easy to understand.

Sometimes some are using like this also:

```
style="color:white; 
       font-size:24px; 
        width:200px"
```

It's  actually doesn't matter. But the best way to do is add a `class` and put all styles to that `class` in a separate `CSS` file. and include it.